# resize scroll bar width in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am new to stackoverflow.

I need to resize the scrollbar width and height.

I tried in many ways, I can get only changing its color but not resizing.

Comment: Post some code or make a fiddle

Comment: What scrollbar? The native one? Don't think you can change it.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, i cant find any code, but in chrome i can do it using the follwing

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

Comment: For that you need to use some Javascript. IE doesn't have any native code like webkit based browsers have.

Comment: can u post some code please

Answer (score 4):

There is no CSS way to change style of browser scrollbars, except webkit-based browsers (Google Chrome, Safari, new Opera). So to make custom scrollbar you have to emulate it with js. There are lots of jQuery plugins - some better, some worse, some matches your needs, some - not. Try these: [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/), [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), [Malihu Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Comment: Thank you, will try it and get back with the result

Answer (score 4):

Although this is a fairly old question.  MSIE has a feature which allow the scrollbars to hide when not being used.  This is very similiar to the scrollbars OSX lion introduced.  Plain CSS , NO JS.

```
  body {

  scrollbar-base-color: #222;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #222;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #222;
  scrollbar-track-color: #3e3e42;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: #111;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #222;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #222; 
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

The example above shows adding custom scrollbars to MSIE and then having them hidden when out of focus with the -ms-autohiding-scrollbar property.

- Note - you can have different scrollbar behaviors for different parts of your site by targeting and #id or .class instead of body.

Comment: does not answer the question in any way

Comment: -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; helped me

Comment: Dear IE!! Why you don't just DIE?