# IE 11 change scrollbar width in css

Tags: css, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

How do I change the width of the scrollbar in IE 11?

here is how Im changing most styles.

```
 body {
   scrollbar-base-color: red;
   scrollbar-3dlight-color: #000;
   scrollbar-highlight-color: blue;
   scrollbar-track-color: green;
   scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
   scrollbar-shadow-color: yellow;
   scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: brown;
 }
```

Here is my working plunkr changing some styles.
http://jsfiddle.net/u6bjqj4u/

I have seen this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10103480/1879992

but I am wondering if there is a pure css way to change IE 11 scrollbar.+
I read this post, but it was not specific to IE 11, and it was written 3 years ago:[resize scroll bar width in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513822/resize-scroll-bar-width-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score -5):

Use *[*Jquery Scrollbar](https://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html)**.IE doesnt support **webkit** which is required for custom scroll bar.

Comment: Expand on your answer. Could you provide links and quotes from the IE documentation?